# Loop with timeout protection that only runs once "as it should"

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a script that restores calendar data from a backup written in a spreadsheet. Since the amount of data is highly unpredictable I designed a loop that stops after a given number of minutes , asking the user to `continue` or to `cancel` while showing the actual counter state (this to prevent issue with Google max execution time limit).

It works pretty well but in this simplified test script I used for testing the idea it works only once : when the first "timeout" occurs, it shows the `continue/cancel` option as expected and then continues from where it started but **when the same condition happens for the second time** the `continue` button doesn't shows up.

My question is simply : why ? or better : what's the difference between both situations ?

The spreadsheet with embedded script is [publicly testable here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dG5kYmstN1NBVlBRb3YweUVnbnJxbVE) (see `menu : test`)

and the whole script is shown below (it's a bit long of course but the interresting part is near the end)

I used `ScriptProperties` to keep track of execution time and to continue the loop from where I left.

```
function onOpen() {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
                     {name: "test", functionName: "test"},  
                      ];  
  ss.addMenu("test", menuEntries);  
}

function test(){
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers',[0,0].join('@'))
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("test");
  app.setHeight(150).setWidth(250);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var handlerCancel = app.createServerHandler('canceltest');
  var handlerContinue = app.createServerHandler('continuetest');
  var contCHandler = app.createClientHandler();
  var cancel = app.createButton("cancel.", handlerCancel).setId('cancel').setVisible(false);
  var cont = app.createButton('continue',handlerContinue).setId('continue').setVisible(false).addClickHandler(contCHandler);
  var button = app.createButton('start').setId('button');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('runtest');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  contCHandler.forTargets(button).setEnabled(false).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  var cHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(cancel).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  button.addClickHandler(handler).addClickHandler(cHandler);
  app.add(panel.add(button).add(cont).add(cancel))//.add(trig));
  doc.show(app);
}

function canceltest(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restoreData','')
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers','canceled');
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('  ','restore aborted');
   app.close()
   return app;  
}  

function continuetest(e){
  runtest(e)
  }

function runtest(e){
  var dStart; var dEnd;
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('startrestore',new Date().getTime().toString())
    if(ScriptProperties.getProperty('restoreData')==null||Utilities.jsonStringify(ScriptProperties.getProperties()).indexOf('restoreData')==-1)
      {ScriptProperties.setProperty('restoreData',Utilities.jsonStringify(e))
      }
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var pointers = ScriptProperties.getProperty('restorePointers');
   if(pointers=='0@0'){
   dStart = 0;
   dEnd = 500;
   }else{
   dStart = Number(pointers.split('@')[0]);
   dEnd = Number(pointers.split('@')[1]);
   }
// main loop --------------------------
      for(var ee=dStart;ee<dEnd;++ee){ // main loop
           var ccc = ScriptProperties.getProperty('restorePointers');
           if(ccc=='canceled'){ app.close();return app};

      Utilities.sleep(85); // simulate some activity


   if((ee/10)==parseInt(ee/10)&&ee>0){
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(ee+' steps completed')
       if(new Date().getTime()-Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty('startrestore'))>12000){ ;//  +- 12 sec timeout
           ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers',[ee,dEnd].join('@'));
           app.getElementById('continue').setHTML('continue from '+ee).setVisible(true)
           return app
           }
        }
    }
// end of main loop-----------------  
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restoreData','')
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers',0+'@'+0);
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('normal process end');
   app.close();
   return app;  
}
```

Comment: I am running into a similar event where functions only fire once although mine is completely button related.  I hope we both get it solved soonish.  I suspect it has something to do with return app killing any handlers that were set originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's keeping the 'continue' button from updating with each interval. Your Server Handler needs to return an app:

```
function continuetest(e){
  return runtest(e)  ///<<<
}
```

This bit, `(ee/10)==parseInt(ee/10)` is an awkward way to evaluate `true` every 10th item. Use modulus instead:

```
if((ee%10==0)&&ee>0){ ///<<< modulus
```

After each pause, the value of ee is repeated in the toast. This can be fixed by remembering what the last displayed value was, and skipping it.

```
if (ee == Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastToast'))) continue; ///<<< don't repeat toast
ScriptProperties.setProperty('lastToast',ee);  ///<<<
```

#### Full script

```
function onOpen() {   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
                     {name: "test", functionName: "test"},  
                      ];  
  ss.addMenu("test", menuEntries);  
}

function test(){
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers',[0,0].join('@'))
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("test");
  app.setHeight(150).setWidth(250);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var handlerCancel = app.createServerHandler('canceltest');
  var handlerContinue = app.createServerHandler('continuetest');
  var contCHandler = app.createClientHandler();
  var cancel = app.createButton("cancel.", handlerCancel).setId('cancel').setVisible(false);
  var cont = app.createButton('continue',handlerContinue).setId('continue').setVisible(false).addClickHandler(contCHandler);
  var start = app.createButton('start').setId('start');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('runtest');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  contCHandler.forTargets(start).setEnabled(false).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  var cHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(cancel).setVisible(true).forEventSource().setVisible(false);
  start.addClickHandler(handler).addClickHandler(cHandler);
  app.add(panel.add(start).add(cont).add(cancel))//.add(trig));
  doc.show(app);
}

function canceltest(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restoreData','')
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers','canceled');
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('  ','restore aborted');
   app.close()
   return app;  
}  

function continuetest(e){
  return runtest(e)  ///<<<
  }

function runtest(e){
  var dStart; var dEnd;
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('startrestore',new Date().getTime().toString())
    if(ScriptProperties.getProperty('restoreData')==null||Utilities.jsonStringify(ScriptProperties.getProperties()).indexOf('restoreData')==-1)
      {ScriptProperties.setProperty('restoreData',Utilities.jsonStringify(e))
      }
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var pointers = ScriptProperties.getProperty('restorePointers');
   if(pointers=='0@0'){
   dStart = 0;
   dEnd = 500;
   }else{
   dStart = Number(pointers.split('@')[0]);
   dEnd = Number(pointers.split('@')[1]);
   }
// main loop --------------------------
      for(var ee=dStart;ee<dEnd;++ee){ // main loop
           var ccc = ScriptProperties.getProperty('restorePointers');
           if(ccc=='canceled'){ app.close();return app};

      Utilities.sleep(85); // simulate some activity


   if((ee%10==0)&&ee>0){ ///<<< modulus
     if (ee == Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastToast'))) continue; ///<<< don't repeat toast
     ScriptProperties.setProperty('lastToast',ee);  ///<<<
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(ee+' steps completed')
       if(new Date().getTime()-Number(ScriptProperties.getProperty('startrestore'))>12000) { //  +- 12 sec timeout  
           ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers',[ee,dEnd].join('@'));
           app.getElementById('continue').setHTML('continue from '+ee).setVisible(true)
           return app
           }
        }
    }
// end of main loop-----------------  
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restoreData','')
   ScriptProperties.setProperty('restorePointers',0+'@'+0);
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('normal process end');
   app.close();
   return app;  
}
```

Comment: As usual, great answer :-) Didn't think about returning the function itself from the continue ... Thanks also for the modulus idea. This is probably symptomatic of my 'amateur' approach of JS programming, I never learned anything other than try/experiment by myself so your answer(s) give(s) me opportunities to learn better, more 'academic'. Thanks for that.

Comment: I had fun with that one, and learned from it too. I haven't done that much wiyh UiApp myself.