# Using time-based trigger to prevent timeout

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that forwards as much as 200 emails at a time from one user to another, and as such causes timeout issues.  My question is, is there an elegant way to use time based triggers to prevent the timeout.  If so, how would I go about doing this?

I have a doPost function which is a response to the user choosing to forward email.  The doPost function then calls a forwardEmails function, which will actually forward the emails.  I have also written a function to add the trigger:

```
  function preempTimeout(fn){
    var date = new Date();
    var newDate = setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 60);
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(fn).timeBased().at(newDate).create();
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at these 2 posts and their answers, it might give you some ideas .

[Loop with timeout protection that only runs once "as it should"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548123/loop-with-timeout-protection-that-only-runs-once-as-it-should)

[What happens when I "sleep" in GAS ? (execution time limit workaround)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886550/what-happens-when-i-sleep-in-gas-execution-time-limit-workaround)